# Psychology of dogpiling

Tags: social-psychology

What is the Psychological explanation behind hoards of people turning on someone, unfairly and unreasonably simply because others have turned on that person? It's like that hate just keeps gaining momentum, facts and logic be damned. Why are people like this? I would take a wild guess that there's some mix of a bystander effect going on and tribal in-group favoritism. If there's a thread where someone's just getting unfairly dogpiled on, I always make an effort to support them. I've been on the receiving end of these dogpiles, it's really the fastest way to lose compassion for humanity, you realize the truth to them is just whatever others in their vicinity think and they they will use strategies of insults, hypocrisy and gaslighting to shut you down.

Comment: Similar to: [I am looking for the name of a phenomenon where people blindly follow others when they sense a threat](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/24991/7001) and [What is the term for human beings' tendency to obey without thinking?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/1022/7001)

Comment: Is dogpiling a synonym of ganging up?